# How do I use Watir to download a file to a specific location in IE9

Tags: watir, browser-automation

In the older versions of IE, there is a popup window.
In IE9 it's a funny looking bar on the bottom.
Anybody had tried anything that works yet?

Answer (score 0):

The only way for now is sending TABs.

For example with Watir and RAutomation

```
ww = Watir::IE.attach(:url, /1.1.1.127/)

#Click on download link
ww.link(:text, /Download_link/).click

#Click on 'Save As' in the 'funny looking bar on the bottom'
wrauto = RAutomation::Window.new(:title => ww.title)
wrauto.send_keys("{TAB}")
wrauto.send_keys("{TAB}")
wrauto.send_keys("{DOWN}")
wrauto.send_keys("{DOWN}")
wrauto.send_keys("{ENTER}")

#popup window to save
w = RAutomation::Window.new(:title => /Save As/)

#Direction that you going to save
w.text_field(:class => "Edit", :index => 0).set path_direction

w.button(:value => "&Save").click
RAutomation::Window.new(:title => /complete/).button(:value => "Close").click
```